# How to enable Chinese input using on-screen keyboard in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchscreen, input-language, chinese, onscreen-keyboard

I am using an Ubuntu machine as a Point-of-Sale system and would like to type Chinese characters using an on-screen keyboard. This way I can pack away my physical keyboard & mouse to have a clean workspace.

I have tried iBus-pinyin, Fcitix-pinyin, Fcitix-sougou but nothing works with on-screen keyboard.

Do you have a new idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having switched to Intelligent Pinyin (provided by the `ibus-libpinyin` package) and enabled GNOME's On Screen Keyboard it worked instantly for me. Since I don't have a touch screen, I used the mouse to click the virtual keys. Clicking b e i j i n g results in 北京.

This works both on Ubuntu 21.04 (which I'm currently using) and Ubuntu 18.04 in VM.

Most likely it doesn't work on Ubuntu with GNOME if you use some Fcitx input source.

Comment: Wow. I think I need to test it again. Maybe need to I install from scratch. I am really happy to see you got it to work! Thanks for your reply, Gunnar!